# Running bash or cmd with Proxifier

Tags: windows, proxy

I'm using Proxifier 3 on Windows 10 (1803). I've successfully created a proxy rule for Google Chrome and certain domain names.

However, I can't make it work for cmd.exe or the WSL terminal (bash).

If I just add cmd.exe or bash.exe in the Applications section, it doesn't work - if I ping from the terminal, it doesn't appear in the connections tab.

If I set "Any" in Applications, everything else works with the proxy, but cmd and bash still don't work.

Answer (score 0):

Proxifier v3.4.2 (2018.08.31) does not support WSL processes. Their support claims they are working on adding it, but it's not ready yet. WSL is changing in 2020 to use a Linux kernel instead of the emulated kernel. This release is referred to as WSL2. This will likely change the requirements for a proxy app. Not clear yet if that will be easier or harder to support.

https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4542

You can contact them: support@proxifier.com